# Disable terminal in Golang

Tags: go

I'm using an external library which asks for a password on terminal or uses a buffer which has to return the correct password. It itself is using [another library](https://github.com/mattn/go-isatty) to check whether a terminal is available. That library says a terminal is available, which is correct.

I want to disable the terminal so that the password from the buffer that I'm providing is used. How can I do that?

Comment: "external library which asks for a password" this is where I'd start looking.  https://github.com/mattn/go-isatty just check whether there's a terminal.  It's the thing using isatty that is going to have to decide whether to use a terminal that exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this library checks if the given file descriptor is from a terminal device, via a syscall. You can just close stdin, and call it a day :) If that library hardcoded `os.Stdout` another solution is needed, because if you close `os.Stdout` you can't use terminal output anymore.

Below code prints false.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/mattn/go-isatty"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    err := os.Stdin.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not close stdin")
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(isatty.IsTerminal(os.Stdin.Fd()))
}
```